# updating database with user edit

Tags: php

I am trying to update my database with a post that a user has edited in a forum.  The whole edit form is functioning excet for when they click edit the form submits and goes to the main forum page, but the database and the post doesn't change.

When the submit edit button is pressed I have this:

```
    <input name="a_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $rows['a_id']; ?>">
    <input name="question_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $rows['question_id']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="edit post">
```

My save edit code is this:

```
 #data preparation for the query 
 $id=intval($_POST['id']);  
 $a_id=intval($_POST['a_id']);
 $question_id=intval($_POST['question_id']);
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
 $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value); 


 $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET a_answer='$_POST[a_answer]' WHERE a_id='$a_id' AND question_id='$question_id'";

 if (!mysql_query($sql)) {  
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
 } 
 mysql_close; 
 header ("location: main_forum.php"); 

 ?>
```

Any ideas???

**EDIT**

For those who find this question useful unlike @mario, the problem was in the variable I was sending to the save edit page.

```
       <input name="a_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $rows['a_id']; ?>">     
<input name="question_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $rows['question_id']; ?>">
```

Should have been

```
    <input name="a_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $a_id; ?>">     
<input name="question_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $question_id; ?>">
```

Comment: That code looks almost the same as in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841763/why-does-my-edit-forum-answers-functionality-update-multiple-fields - In particular you didn't apply some of the advise given in comments. -- Here is another one: Read some tutorials on basic debugging. -- Your questions are a bit boring, line-by-line fixes are not what Stackoverflow is intended for. And you already posted a dozen on your extremely basic forum script.

Comment: In my previous post the edit was updating all the answer posts. Now it isn't updating any? - I don't mean to bore you. I am extremely new to all of this and this is the last thing i need to fix on my page for it to function fully.

Comment: You didn't give any relevant to details to tell why. Print your SQL and print your data, compare it with the database, run the query manually (PhpMyAdmin) to find out. Try to find the reason yourself for once. -- Don't post any more questions about this.

Comment: Feel free to stop reading my questions if you have a problem with them

Comment: @mario: A little harsh. If you don't want to answer then you don't have to. The question may not be terribly interesting, but it's still valid.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes. It's actually a valid question. Not answereable due to the lack of concrete information on the data. And looking over the previous user account (the one I could find) the question is also a step up quality-wise. But nevertheless, 10 questions are enough for a single topic. I suspect the whole code was written by SO. No problem with simple questions, but this asker is straining it (particularly by severing the question history). A forum would be more appropriate to work on the code.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I would make the syntax a bit nicer.

```
$foor    =     $bar;
foreach()
{

}
```

Than I would not work with the $_POST like that. make an array such as
$data=array()

than you go

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
     $data[$key] => mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

And after that your $sql needs to look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET a_answer=`$data[a_answer]` WHERE a_id=$a_id AND question_id=$question_id";
```

Then, if I were you I would make a print on your $sql.

Comment: I agree with Richard, adding a print statement so you van visually validate the SQL will be helpful.

I'd also update Richard's sql to this:

$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET a_answer='{$data[a_answer]}' WHERE a_id=$a_id AND question_id=$question_id";

... adding quotes and braces around the array reference.

Comment: -1 How does completely breaking the syntax make it "a bit nicer"? You have made a number of syntax errors in your suggestions. Finally, please use the preview pane when writing questions/answers, to check formatting.